# Make css map points to sass partial using grunt

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-cssmin, grunt-contrib-sass

I'm using grunt-contrib-css to process my sass files, this is the workflow im following:

- *partial.sass* contains all the styles.
- *home.sass* import *partial.sass*.
- *home.css* gets created from *home.sass*.
- *home.min.css* is the minified version of *home.css*, and the one included on the .html file.

However, the map for home.min.css points to home.css but what I need is the map to be related to the partial file. is this possible?

*PD:* I'm using grunt-contrib-sass to process the sass file and grunt-contrib-cssmin to minify the css.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need use grunt-contrib-cssmin to minify your css, grunt sass task does that.

use   `style: "compressed",` to get a minified file and    `style: "expanded",` for debuging with line number

bellow a sample for you solve this.

gruntfile.js

```
     //src ===============================
        var src;
        config.src = src = {
            sassMain: 'scss/home.sass',
            distFolder: 'public/stylesheets/app.dist.css',
            devFolder: 'public/stylesheets/app.dev.css',
            sassFolder: 'scss/**/*.sass'
        };

        //Sass ===============================
            var sass;
            config.sass = sass = {};

            //distribution
            sass.dist = {
                options: {
                    style: "compressed",
                    noCache: true,
                    sourcemap: 'none',
                    update: true
                },
                files: {
                    "<%= src.distFolder %>": "<%= src.sassMain %>"
                }
            };

            //development env.
            sass.dev = {
                options: {
                    style: "expanded",
                    lineNumber: true,
                },
                files: {
                    "<%= src.devFolder %>": "<%= src.sassMain %>"
                }
            };

grunt.registerTask('dev', ['concat:dev', 'sass:dev']);
    grunt.registerTask('dist', ['concat:dev', 'sass:dist']);
```

I hope this can help you.